# Detach couple the same elements and insert only one

Tags: jquery

I have the same three forms on one page and there are the same three buttons in them. I want move this buttons (for creating another design of each form).
The problem is when use "detach()" and then "insertAfter()" - i have all three buttons in each form. But I need only one button in one form.

There is my HTML:

```
<form action="">
<p>
    <input type="text" class="text">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox"> unsubscribe
</p>
<div class="button">
    <input type="submit">   
</div>
```

And there is my jquery:

```
var btn = $( '.button' );
btn.each(function(){    
  $( this ).detach();
  $( this ).insertAfter($( 'input[type="email"]' ));
});
```

And what I have:

```
<form action="">
<p>
    <input type="text" class="text">
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" />     
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" />     
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" />     
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox"> unsubscribe
</p>
```

**Here the result** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wishmaker/06v23yrn/1/)

It doesnt work. I'm probably thinking wrong...

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide a http://jsfiddle.net link to reproduce your code..if i understood your problem, you need to assign an id to each of your form and add button only to the form you want to add..eg:      $('#formID selector').append("HTML");

Comment: Yeah, the ID is solution. But i work with Wordpress and these forms - are widgets...  ID's come dynamically.

Comment: it unclear what output you are expecting..pls post the expected markup..and why are you using detach and reinserting the button div element after the input text box..since you have three different .button elements in each form, it loops three times and creates three buttons and inserts after the text box..i think there is no use of detach line since you are not using it for later use